# Copy constructor for classes with atomic member

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

I have a class with an atomic member and i want to write a copy constructor:

```
struct Foo
{
    std::atomic<int> mInt;

    Foo() {}
    Foo(const Foo& pOther)
    {
        std::atomic_store(mInt, std::atomic_load(pOther.mInt, memory_order_relaxed), memory_order_relaxed);
    }
};
```

But i don't know which ordering i must use, because i don't know where and when this copy constructor will be called.

Can i use `relaxed` ordering for copy constructor and assignment operator?

Comment: What about *not* providing the copy constructor but a function that takes the memory order from the user? (same goes for assignment)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I can't do this, for example i want use this class as template argument for another class, and that class only call copy constructor

Comment: There is a reason why the standard atomic types don't have copy constructors... if you *need* this, then the only sane thing to do is to use sequential consistency, slower but safe. Any other alternative and you might end up with unwanted data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, if you don't know how it will be used, you should use `memory_order_seq_cst` to be safe. If you use `memory_order_relaxed`, you could run into issues with instructions being reordered.

Comment: The load from the existing `Foo` should default to `seq_cst`, but it makes no sense for the constructor of an atomic object to need strong ordering for its store.  Anything that makes the address of the newly-constructed object available to other threads will need to use a release-store to make sure the constructor is done before another thread can use it.  See my answer: pass the loaded value as an initializer, instead of using a store.

Answer (score 3):

The `std::atomic<T>` template deletes its copy-constructor, because atomics are for *shared state*, so copying them to another atomic is usually not what you want.

Deleting the copy-constructor forces users of your class to think about what they're doing, and document that they're doing an atomic-load of one value and then passing that copy to somewhere else.  (e.g. `atomic<some_struct> var1 (var2.load())`).  See [C++11: write move constructor with atomic<bool> member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14182258/c11-write-move-constructor-with-atomicbool-member/14183013#14183013)

---

The constructor for `std::atomic<T>` [is not itself atomic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/atomic), so it makes little sense to worry about the ordering of a store to it in your constructor (unless your constructor called a bunch of other functions and put the address of `mInt` somewhere that another thread could get it...)

Even better, use the copied value as an initializer, instead of doing an atomic store at all.  (See also [Nonlocking Way to Copy Atomics in Copy Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33723142/nonlocking-way-to-copy-atomics-in-copy-constructor)).

I think the only way this could be a problem is if you were doing something that's already undefined-behaviour, like using [placement-`new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) to construct a new `Foo` object in an already-shared location that could be read/written by other threads as you did this.  This is obviously insane, so don't do that.

Having your class's memory-ordering behaviour match `std::atomic<T>`'s constructor (i.e. none for storing the initializer) seems like a good idea.

---

Only the caller knows whether sequential-consistency is required for the load from the source operand.  Thus, you should let the caller choose by accepting a memory-order argument, with default=seq_cst (for consistency with `std::atomic`, not because that's what anyone is likely to want for this case).  And yes, this is legal C++: [copy constructor with default arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787569/copy-constructor-with-default-arguments)

```
#include <atomic>

struct Foo
{
    std::atomic<int> mInt;

    Foo() {}
    Foo(const Foo& pOther, std::memory_order order = std::memory_order_seq_cst)
        : mInt(pOther.mInt.load(order))
    {}
};
```

This compiles the way I expected: with ordering for the load but no ordering for the store.  (e.g. looking at the asm output for ARM64 shows that the load uses `ldar` to do an acquire-load, but the store is just a simple `str`).

I tested it with this caller [(Godbolt compiler explorer)](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:'%23include+%3Catomic%3E%0A%0Astruct+Foo%0A%7B%0A++++std::atomic%3Cint%3E+mInt%3B%0A%0A++++Foo()+%7B%7D%0A++++Foo(const+Foo%26+pOther,+std::memory_order+order+%3D+std::memory_order_seq_cst)%0A++++++++:+mInt(pOther.mInt.load(order))%0A++++%7B%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Avoid+extf(Foo+%26)%3B%0A%0Avoid+test(const+Foo+*p)%0A%7B%0A++++Foo+tmp(*p)%3B%0A++++extf(tmp)%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:33.344394394597536,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:arm64g630,filters:(___0:(),b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0',jquery:'3.2.1',length:1,prevObject:(___0:(sizzle1504571495915:(undefined:(legend:!(5,0,'1')))),length:1,prevObject:(___0:(jQuery321073054571485486371:(display:''),sizzle1504571495915:(undefined:(legend:!(5,0,'1')))),length:1))),options:'-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B11+-O3+-Wall+-Wextra',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'ARM64+gcc+6.3.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)',t:'0')),header:(),k:32.91585939773626,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-stdlib%3Dlibc%2B%2B+-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B11+-O3+-Wall+-Wextra',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)',t:'0')),k:33.7397462076662,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) which constructs one on the stack and then passes its address to a non-inline function that might make that address available to other threads.  So it can't optimize away.

```
void extf(Foo &);    // non-inline function

void test(const Foo *p) {
    Foo tmp(*p);
    extf(tmp);
}
```

**Whatever `extf()` does to make the address available to other threads should use a release-store, which ensures that any other thread which sees that address will see a properly-constructed `Foo`.**  This is a normal requirement, and is why it's totally fine that the initializer isn't even atomic.

---

Note that it's impossible to do a move between two different memory locations as a single atomic operation (in C++11 or on any hardware I'm aware of), so it's unlikely that a strong ordering will be useful.

Even defining whether such a move is atomic or not is problematic, because atomicity only exists in the eyes of an observer.  Since it's impossible to observe two memory locations at the same time it's a meaningless concept.  (Unless they're adjacent and you can get them both with a single atomic load).

Comment: Motorola 680x0-series had for a while a [CAS2](http://68k.hax.com/CAS2) or (aka DCAS) which let you atomically CAS two non-contiguous memory locations. I think they got rid of it later since it is evidently pretty hard to implement this efficiently. To some extent, HTM is the modern replacement.

Answer (score 1):

You only need a stronger memory ordering than `memory_order_relaxed`, if your copy operation is supposed to synchronize with other operations on a different thread.
However, this is almost never the case, as a thread safe copy constructor will almost always require some external synchronization or an extra mutex anyway.