# C++ Getting Error with Assignment operator for Atomic Members in class

Tags: c++, variable-assignment, atomic, assignment-operator, stdatomic

Here is a Simple code to show my problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

using namespace std;

class T {
public:
atomic<int> a;
};

int main() {
int x;
T X,Y;
x = 10;
X.a = x;
Y = X;
cout << Y.a;
}
```

I get the following error Message when I run this :

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:

test.cpp:16:5: error: use of deleted function ‘T& T::operator=(const T&)’

Y = X;
     ^

test.cpp:6:7: note: ‘T& T::operator=(const T&)’ is implicitly deleted 
because the default definition would be ill-formed:

 class T {
       ^

test.cpp:6:7: error: use of deleted function ‘std::atomic<int>& std::atomic<int>::operator=(const std::atomic<int>&)’

In file included from test.cpp:2:0:

/usr/include/c++/6/atomic:617:15: note: declared here
       atomic& operator=(const atomic&) = delete;
```

Comment: Assignment between object of the same type (like you have with `Y = X`) is called *copy* assignment. And an [`std::atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) can't be copied.

Comment: This may also be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961043/copy-constructor-for-classes-with-atomic-member

Comment: The error message is perfectly clear.   `std::atomic<int>` does not have an `operator=()` that accepts an argument of type `std::atomic<int>`.   Which is completely correct - the C++11 standard specifies that `operator=()` for the template type `std::atomic` is explicitly `delete`d.   Since your `T` contains a `std::atomic<int>` the compiler cannot give `T` an `operator=()`.   The statement `Y = X` requires there to be an `operator=()`.

Comment: Note that in C, `struct` assignment with an `_Atomic` member will completely ignore `_Atomic` and do a regular copy of the entire struct object  (unlike C++).  (With no compiler warning from gcc or clang.)  https://godbolt.org/g/heUd1R.