# When initializing an atomic class member it requires a 'deleted' function, but adding it would make it no longer trivially copyable

Tags: c++11, stdatomic

When initializing an atomic class member it requires a 'deleted' function, but adding it would make it no longer trivially copyable which is a requirement for an object/struct to be atomic.  Am I just not understanding how to do this correctly, or is this a problem in the c++ standard?

Take the example below:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <cstdint>

template<typename T>
struct A
{
    T * data;
    std::atomic<uintptr_t> next;
};

template<typename T>
class B
{
    std::atomic<A<T>> myA;

    public:
    B ( A<T>  & a ) noexcept
    { 
        myA.store(a, std::memory_order_relaxed );
    }
};  

int main ()
{
    A<int> a;
    B<int> b(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Trying to compile this with g++ gives `error: use of deleted function 'A<int>::A(const A<int>&)' myA.store(a, std::memory_order_relaxed);`.  My understanding of this error is that the atomic::store method is looking for that constructor in my `struct A` but not finding it.

Now here is what happens when I add that constructor:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <cstdint>

template<typename T>
struct A
{
    T * data;
    std::atomic<uintptr_t> next;
    A(const A<T>& obj) { } 
    A( ) { } 

};

template<typename T>
class B
{
    std::atomic<A<T>> myA;

    public:
    B ( A<T>  & a ) noexcept
    { 
        myA.store(a, std::memory_order_relaxed );
    }
};  

int main ()
{
    A<int> a;
    B<int> b(a);
    return 0;
}
```

I no longer receive the above compiler error but a new one coming from the requirements of the atomic class `required from 'class B<int>' .... error: static assertion failed:  std::atomic requires a trivially copyable type ...`  In other words by adding the used-defined constructors I have made my `struct A` a non-trivially copyable object which cannot be initialized in `class B`.  However, without the user-defined constructors I cannot use the `store` method in `myA.store(a, std::memory_order_relaxed)`.

This seems like a flaw in the design of the  `std::atomic` class.  Now maybe I am just doing something wrong because I don't have a lot of experience using C++11 and up (I'm old school).  Since 11 there have been a lot of changes and the requirements seem to be a lot stricter.  I'm hoping someone can tell me how to achieve what I want to achieve.

Also I cannot change `std::atomic<A<T>> myA;` to `std::atomic<A<T>> * myA;` (changed to pointer) or `std::atomic<A<T>*> myA;`.  I realize this will compile but it will destroy the fundamental design of a class I am trying to build.

Comment: Which operations on `B<T>` do you want to be atomic, exactly?  And why does it need an *atomic* `A<T>` *value*?  If this is supposed to be an ABA counter, you need union hacks and you need to check that the relevant `atomic<>` objects are lock-free for it to even hope to be safe.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38984153/how-can-i-implement-aba-counter-with-c11-cas

Comment: And BTW: the constructor for a struct with an atomic member should pass a parameter to the `atomic<T>` constructor, instead of using the default constructor and then doing an atomic store.  See my answer on [Copy constructor for classes with atomic member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961043/copy-constructor-for-classes-with-atomic-member/46045691#46045691)

Answer (score 3):

The problem here resides in the fact that `std::atomic` requires a [trivially copiable type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TriviallyCopyable). This because trivially copyable types are the only sure types in C++ which can be directly copied by copying their memory contents directly (eg. through `std::memcpy`). Also non-formerly trivially copyable types could be safe to raw copy but no assumption can be made on this.

This is indeed important for `std::atomic` since copy on temporary values is made through `std::memcpy`, see some [implementation details](https://libcxx.llvm.org/atomic_design_c.html) for Clang for example.

Now at the same time `std::atomic` is not copy constructible, and this is for reasonable reasons, check [this answer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyConstructible) for example, so it's implicitly not trivially copyable (nor any type which contains them).

If, absurdly, you would allow a `std::atomic` to contain another `std::atomic`, and the implementation of `std::atomic` contains a lock, how would you manage copying it atomically? How should it work?