# Initialize atomic members in aggregate

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, stdatomic, aggregate-initialization

There seems no way to initialize atomic members in aggregate using C++14. The following doesn't work ([live on gcc 8.0.1](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fimEyGcdc25ECyGr)):

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>

struct stru {
  std::atomic_int32_t val_0;
  std::atomic_int32_t val_1;
};

int main() {
  auto p = new stru{0, 1};
  std::cout << p->val_0 << ", " << p->val_1 << std::endl; 
}
```

The error message:

```
error: use of deleted function 'std::atomic<int>::atomic(const std::atomic<int>&)'
   auto p = new stru{0, 1};
                     ^
```

This is because atomic types are neither copyable nor movable, and is thus not copy-initializable. The following seems to work however ([live on gcc 8.0.1](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nwDPjbm5wcduaEy0)).

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>

struct stru {
  std::atomic_int32_t val_0;
  std::atomic_int32_t val_1;
};

int main() {
  auto p = new stru{};
  std::cout << p->val_0 << ", " << p->val_1 << std::endl; 
}
```

This effectively performs zero initialization, and is thus unable to initialize to values other than zero. Is there any way to initialize to other specified values?

Comment: Don't post links to your compiler spew, post the spew.

Comment: Your first code block compiles without warnings/errors on VS2017 and runs as expected.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @jwdonahue If different compilers disagree, then one got to be correct while the other be wrong. VS is known to be non-standard-conforming. BTW, what do you mean by *post the spew*?

Comment: He means **Put the error message in the question.**

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks, updated.

Comment: @jwdonahue And there is no way to specify C++14 in VS. It always tries to follow the latest standard.

Comment: Have you tried the VS option [/std:c++14](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version) to specify the language version you want? :-)

Comment: @BoPersson Wow O_O Today I learned.

Comment: Apologies to all.  I normally would have put some time into a standards check, compiler options, etc, and posted an answer, but I was being pulled away from my hobby by more pressing matters.

Comment: @HDJEMAI: The same thing happens in clang; the C++ tag is more appropriate than [tag:gcc8]; it's not specific to gcc8.  Rolled back your tag edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Patrick's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48837672/1348273) works, but his explanation doesn't look right to me. So I post the explanation I find here. For the code `auto p = new stru{{0}, {1}};` [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) kicks in with the effect:

> If the initializer clause is a nested braced-init-list (which is not
>   an expression), the corresponding array element/class member/**public
>   base (since C++17)** is list-initialized from that clause: aggregate
>   initialization is recursive.

As a result, instead of copy initialization, the members are copy list-initialized from the braced-init-list.

Comment: Related: [Copy constructor for classes with atomic member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961043/copy-constructor-for-classes-with-atomic-member/46045691#46045691): if you are writing a custom constructor (regular constructor or (probably a bad idea) copy-constructor): definitely pass args to the `std::atomic` constructor with `:atomic_member(a)` syntax, rather than using an atomic store (assignment) inside the constructor after letting an atomic member be default-initialized.

Comment: @PeterCordes Indeed. However, I'm somewhat concerned with `atomic_flag`. It seems that only the `std::atomic_flag v = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;` syntax is guaranteed to work (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT)). So, I'm wondering whether `:atomic_member(a)` is OK, or do I have to use in-class default member initializer.

Comment: I'm talking about the `std::atomic<T>` template; `std::atomic_flag` is allowed by the standard to be different, I think because it's the only one that's guaranteed to be lock-free.  `:atomic_member(a)` is definitely ok (and is lock-free for `int` / `long` and other small `T` types on typical C++ implementations).  `:atomic_flag_member(a)` isn't guaranteed to even compile, because `std::atomic_flag` doesn't have a value constructor.  (It might compile on implementations where it doesn't need to be special and is defined on top of `std::atomic<bool>`; the standard *allows* it to be special.)

Comment: When you say "the members are copy initialized from the braced-init-list" -- which constructor is picked in that case?

Comment: @PatrickCollins It means if the selected constructor is declared `explicit`, the program is ill-formed. For example, `unique_ptr<int> p = {new int()}` won't compile.

Answer (score -1):

`1` and `0` aren't `std::atomic_int32_t`s. The following works:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>

struct stru {
  std::atomic_int32_t val_0;
  std::atomic_int32_t val_1;
};

int main() {
  auto p = new stru{{0}, {1}};
  std::cout << p->val_0 << ", " << p->val_1 << std::endl; 
}
```

EDIT: Why does this happen? [Copy initialization kicks in](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) for each element in the initializer list:

> Each direct public...non-static class member, in order of array subscript/appearance in the class definition, is copy-initialized from the corresponding clause of the initializer list.

In your example, `1` and `0` are implicitly converted to `std::atomic_int32_t`, and a `std::atomic_int32_t` can't be copy-initialized from a `std::atomic_int32_t`. In the extra `{}` version, `val_0` and `val_1` are copy initialized from `std::initializer_list<int>`s, which is fine.

Comment: Could you explain the details of what happened here?

Comment: I don't think your explanation is correct. I've posted the explanation I find.