# In c++, if I create a constructor that takes one argument which has a default value - will that serve as a default (empty) constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, default-constructor

Does the following one-parameter constructor also serve as a default constructor?

```
class SomeClass
    {
    public:
        SomeClass(const int &a = 4);
    }
```

(Assuming the constructor is well defined etc.)

Thanks!

Comment: I take it you tried to run it?

Comment: Did you try copying the class with this code?

Comment: Yes, potentially it will. You can do weird things like make a default constructor that is also the copy constructor. See https://punchlet.wordpress.com/2009/12/03/letter-the-third/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2787569/3002139 is closely related.

Comment: I think it's not *copy constructor*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the definition of default constructor allows parameters as long as they have default values:

> A *default constructor* for a class `X` is a constructor of class `X` for which each parameter that is not a function parameter pack has a default argument (including the case of a constructor with no parameters).

(from the C++1z draft)

Older phrasing:

> A *default constructor* for a class `X` is a constructor of class `X` that can be called without an argument.

---

In addition, your copy constructor will be implicitly defined as defaulted, because you haven't declared one.

There is no such thing as a "default copy constructor".  But "default constructor" and "defaulted copy constructor" are meaningful.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Also, the standard wording is somewhat more reliable than cppreference.  A couple times the cppreference paraphrase has changed the meaning in an important way.

Comment: ... and this is why we use `explicit`, to guard against unintended conversions